# Wordnet 3.0 installation issue on Fedora 17

Tags: linux, wordnet

I am trying to install wordnet 3.0 on Fedora 17

I have downloaded tar.gz for wordnet 3.0 from their website.

I have executed following successfully uptil now:

`tar xzf WordNet-3.0.tar.gz`
`cd WordNet-3.0.tar.gz`
`./configure`

following was output created on console

```
`checking for gcc... gcc  
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out  
checking whether the C compiler works... yes  
checking whether we are cross compiling... no  
checking for suffix of executables...  
checking for suffix of object files... o  
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes  
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes  
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed  
checking for ranlib... ranlib  
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c  
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E  
checking for egrep... grep -E  
checking for ANSI C header files... yes  
checking for sys/types.h... yes  
checking for sys/stat.h... yes  
checking for stdlib.h... yes  
checking for string.h... yes  
checking for memory.h... yes  
checking for strings.h... yes  
checking for inttypes.h... yes  
checking for stdint.h... yes  
checking for unistd.h... yes  
checking locale.h usability... yes  
checking locale.h presence... yes  
checking for locale.h... yes  
checking malloc.h usability... yes  
checking malloc.h presence... yes  
checking for malloc.h... yes  
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes  
checking for string.h... (cached) yes  
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes  
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes  
checking for strchr... yes  
checking for strdup... yes  
checking for strrchr... yes  
checking for strstr... yes  
checking for strtol... yes  
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes  
checking whether build environment is sane... yes  
checking for gawk... gawk  
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes  
checking for style of include used by make... GNU  
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3  
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: WARNING: Can't find Tcl configuration   definitions`
```

But when i try to execute "make", following message comes as output:

```
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`
```

does anybody know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after installing the dev packages for tk8.4-dev and tcl-8.4-dev

Then running configure with:

```
./configure --with-tk=/usr/lib/tk8.4/ --with-tcl=/usr/lib/tcl8.4/
```

(Hints from post: http://shalini-gupta.livejournal.com/42017.html)